# High load when playing music files audio or video

Tags: video, filesystem, music, cpu-load

Why do I keep getting high loads when I play music videos and audio files? Sometimes the computer hangs and everything stops working because of filesystem corruption and I have to repair it before am be able to login again.

I use ubuntu 15.04 64 bit, ext4 filesystem. the players that have experienced this include : totem, rhythmbox and banshee. This has led me to believe its not the players though.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ofcourse the problem was my harddisk. I replaced the harddisk after performing some SMART tests and critical tests failed. Now I listen to music 24/7